# wpf Combobox Itemssource not binding within Listbox Data Template

Tags: wpf, combobox, listbox, datatemplate, itemssource

Please help to fix the below issue.
I have Combobox inside listbox item datatemplate so that I can load multiple combobox but same itemsource

```
<StackPanel>
  <ListBox Width="400" Name="lstFiles" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <Grid Name="dataGrid">
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <TextBox Name="dragFileName"
                   Margin="5,0,0,0"
                   Text="{Binding fileName, UpdateSourceTrigger=Default}" />
          <ComboBox Grid.Row="0"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Margin="5,0,0,0"
                    Name="cboDragDocType"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding dragDocType, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, Mode=TwoWay}"  
                    Text="{Binding dragDocTypeText}"
                    IsEditable="True"
                    IsReadOnly="True" />
          <Button Name="dragDelBtn"
                  Grid.Column="2"
                  Height="20">X</Button>
        </Grid>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  </ListBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Data is loading in comboBox by using ObservableCollection property. In Initialize method i do for loop method to get multiple items. 
Problem scenario: Select item from the dropdown1 --> then Select item from the dropdown2 -->Again click dropdown1, Now dropdown1 itemssource is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a binding to the [`SelectedItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selecteditem(v=vs.110).aspx) (or [`SelectedValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvalue(v=vs.110).aspx)) property of the [`ComboBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox(v=vs.110).aspx). Therefore the value cannot be saved (or retrieved).

You need to add a property in your class that acts as the DataContext to hold the selected item of the `ComboBox`, for example:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="0"
          ...
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedDragDocType, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" />
```

As a side-note having both [IsEditable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox.iseditable(v=vs.110).aspx) and [IsReadOnly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox.isreadonly(v=vs.110).aspx) properties on the `ComboBox` set to `true` is pretty restrictive. Are you sure it is the intended behavior?

Comment: Thanks for your response but I meant to say that After comeback to dropdown1(Combobox) when I click Dropdown arrow button it doesn't list values i.e., there is no items in combobox.

Comment: What is exactly your intended behavior? I find it weird to have a `TwoWay` binding on the `ComboBox`'s `ItemsSource` property, since it is not possible to edit the collection that way.

Comment: 1. I have Generic list 
    public class DragOperation
        {
            public string fileName { get; set; }
            public ObservableCollection<ComboBoxItem> dragDocType {     get; set; }
           public string dragDocTypeText { get; set; }
    } by using this list I attached Itemssource to combobox

2. In initialize event of mainwindow  I add data to the Generic list that generic list i.e., by using for loop I am loading 5 combobox
3. At runtime first time it properly loading all data in combobox 
4. When I click again The item source of Combobox is empty.

Comment: Sorry I don't get it. Try explaining without code. With picture(s) maybe (by updating your question).

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to post images.
Very simple.. I have combobox within listbox data template. While runtime all comboboxs having itemssource. 
1. I select an item from First Combobox 2. I select an item from second combobox. 3. When I try to again select an item from first combobox the it is empty(i.e., itemsource of first combobox is empty)